# How do I get org-mobile working correctly?

Tags: mobile, emacs, org-mode

I have been trying to get org-mobile to work on my machine with little
success. I have read many previous answers from this mailing list to no
avail.

When I try to run org-mobile-push I get an error in the minibuffer: "Wrong
type argument: listp, todo".

I have attached a Backtrace of the error and my org-mode settings. I also
attached a debugger eval of the "todo" variable, which I think (I'm not
great at elisp) is causing the error.

Can anyone tell me how I can get org-mobile-push to work correctly?

Cheers!

---- Backtrace and org settings follow ----

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable todo)
 eval(todo)
 eval-expression(todo)
 debugger-eval-expression(todo)
 call-interactively(debugger-eval-expression nil nil)
 recursive-edit()
 byte-code("\306^P
@\307=\203!^@\310\311\312\"\210\313\311!\211^ZA@)\242\314=\203!^@\310\315\312\"\210\316^K!\210\317
\210\320
!\210\f\203d^@\321ed\"^MV\203W^@eb\210\322^M\245y\210`^^^[db\210\322^M\245^MZy\210^N^[`|\210)\323c\210eb\210\324\325\326
\"\210\327\306!\210\324\330!\210\331\312^^^\^^^]\324\330!\210\212\332
\210+\331\207" [unread-command-char debugger-args x debugger-buffer
noninteractive debugger-batch-max-lines -1 debug backtrace-debug 4 t
backtrace-frame lambda 5 pop-to-buffer debugger-mode debugger-setup-buffer
count-lines 2 "...\n" message "%s" buffer-string kill-emacs "" nil
recursive-edit middlestart buffer-read-only standard-output] 4)

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp todo)
 car(todo)
 (setq type (car e) match (nth 1 e) settings (nth 2 e))
 (while (setq e (pop cmds)) (setq type (car e) match (nth 1 e) settings
(nth 2 e)) (setq settings (append gsettings settings)) (setq settings (cons
... settings)) (push (list type match settings) new))
 (cond ((stringp ...)) ((eq ... ...)) ((memq ... ...)) ((and ... ...))
((memq ... ...) (setq key ... desc ... type ... match ... settings ...)
(setq settings ...) (push ... new)) ((or ... ...)) (t (setq gkey ... gdesc
... gsettings ... cmds ...) (setq cnt 0) (while ... ... ... ... ...)))
 (while (setq e (pop thelist)) (cond (...) (...) (...) (...) (... ... ...
...) (...) (t ... ... ...)))
 (let ((custom-list ...) (default-list ...) thelist new e key desc type
match settings cmds gkey gdesc gsettings cnt) (cond (... ...) (... ...)
(... ... ... ...) (... ... ...)) (while (setq e ...) (cond ... ... ... ...
... ... ...)) (and new (list "X" "SUMO" ... ...)))
 org-mobile-sumo-agenda-command()
 (let* ((file ...) (file1 ...) (sumo ...) (org-agenda-custom-commands ...)
(org-mobile-creating-agendas t)) (unless (file-writable-p file1) (error
"Cannot write to file %s" file1)) (when sumo (org-store-agenda-views))
(when org-mobile-use-encryption (org-mobile-encrypt-and-move file1 file)
(delete-file file1) (org-mobile-cleanup-encryption-tempfile)))
 org-mobile-create-sumo-agenda()
 (let ((inhibit-redisplay t)) (org-mobile-create-sumo-agenda))
 (save-window-excursion (run-hooks (quote org-mobile-pre-push-hook))
(org-mobile-check-setup) (org-mobile-prepare-file-lists) (message "Creating
agendas...") (let (...) (org-mobile-create-sumo-agenda)) (message "Creating
agendas...done") (org-save-all-org-buffers) (message "Copying files...")
(org-mobile-copy-agenda-files) (message "Writing index file...")
(org-mobile-create-index-file) (message "Writing checksums...")
(org-mobile-write-checksums) (run-hooks (quote org-mobile-post-push-hook)))
 (save-excursion (save-window-excursion (run-hooks ...)
(org-mobile-check-setup) (org-mobile-prepare-file-lists) (message "Creating
agendas...") (let ... ...) (message "Creating agendas...done")
(org-save-all-org-buffers) (message "Copying files...")
(org-mobile-copy-agenda-files) (message "Writing index file...")
(org-mobile-create-index-file) (message "Writing checksums...")
(org-mobile-write-checksums) (run-hooks ...)))
 (let ((org-agenda-buffer-name "*SUMO*") (org-agenda-filter
org-agenda-filter) (org-agenda-redo-command org-agenda-redo-command))
(save-excursion (save-window-excursion ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
... ... ... ... ...)))
 (let ((a-buffer ...)) (let (... ... ...) (save-excursion ...))
(redraw-display) (when (and a-buffer ...) (if ... ... ...)))
 org-mobile-push()
 call-interactively(org-mobile-push t nil)
 execute-extended-command(nil)
 call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Emacs  : GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.4)
of 2011-04-04 on rothera, modified by Debian
Package: Org-mode version 7.7

## current state:

```
(setq
 org-log-done 'time
 org-export-latex-after-initial-vars-hook '(org-beamer-after-initial-vars)
 org-speed-command-hook '(org-speed-command-default-hook
             org-babel-speed-command-hook)
 org-agenda-custom-commands '(("c" "TODO list, Priority down" todo
"NEXTACTION"
                  ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (priority-down)))
               )
                  ("/media/sf_Conor/todolistprioritydown.ps"))
                 ("x" "Todo List and Agenda"
                  (todo (quote (priority-down))
               (agenda "" (org-agenda-ndays 1)))
                  ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (time-up))))
                  ("/media/sf_Conor/todolistprioritydown.ps"))
                 ("w" "other Work" tags-todo "DONE"
                  ((org-agenda-files
                (quote
                 ("/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/todo.org"))
                )
               (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
                (quote (priority-up effort-down)))
               )
                  ("/media/sf_Conor/computer.html"))
                 ("p" "Priority List" tags-todo
                  ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (priority-up)))))
                 )
 org-agenda-files '("/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/
accountmanagement.org"
           "/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/heritage.org"
           "/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/arbitrage.org"
           "/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/kontagent.org"
           "/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/todo.org")
 org-blocker-hook '(org-block-todo-from-children-or-siblings-or-parent)
 org-agenda-exporter-settings '((ps-number-of-columns 2) (ps-landscape-mode
t)
               (org-agenda-add-entry-text-maxlines 5)
               (htmlize-output-type (quote css)))
 org-metaup-hook '(org-babel-load-in-session-maybe)
 org-after-todo-state-change-hook '(wicked/org-clock-out-if-waiting
                   wicked/org-clock-in-if-starting
                   org-clock-out-if-current)
 org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled t
 org-show-entry-below t
 org-export-blocks-postblock-hook '(org-exp-res/src-name-cleanup)
 org-export-latex-format-toc-function 'org-export-latex-format-toc-default
 org-mobile-inbox-for-pull "/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/
from-mobile.org"
 org-tab-first-hook '(org-hide-block-toggle-maybe
org-src-native-tab-command-maybe
             org-babel-hide-result-toggle-maybe)
 org-src-mode-hook '(org-src-babel-configure-edit-buffer
            org-src-mode-configure-edit-buffer)
 org-confirm-shell-link-function 'yes-or-no-p
 org-export-first-hook '(org-beamer-initialize-open-trackers)
 org-clock-persist t
 org-agenda-before-write-hook '(org-agenda-add-entry-text)
 org-agenda-start-with-follow-mode t
 org-directory "/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/Orgmode/2011/"
 org-export-docbook-xslt-proc-command ""
 org-babel-pre-tangle-hook '(save-buffer)
 org-cycle-hook '(org-cycle-hide-archived-subtrees org-cycle-hide-drawers
         org-cycle-show-empty-lines
         org-optimize-window-after-visibility-change)
 org-export-preprocess-before-normalizing-links-hook
'(org-remove-file-link-modifiers)
 org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks nil
 org-mode-hook '((lambda nil (org-set-local (quote yas/trigger-key) [tab])
         (define-key yas/keymap [tab] (quote yas/next-field-group))
         (define-key org-mode-map "\301"
          (quote org-archive-to-archive-sibling))
         )
        org-clock-load
        (lambda nil
         (org-add-hook (quote change-major-mode-hook)
          (quote org-show-block-all) (quote append) (quote local))
         )
        (lambda nil
         (org-add-hook (quote change-major-mode-hook)
          (quote org-babel-show-result-all) (quote append) (quote local))
         )
        org-babel-result-hide-spec org-babel-hide-all-hashes)
 org-refile-targets '(:level . 2)
 org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook '(org-babel-hash-at-point
org-babel-execute-safely-maybe)
 org-confirm-elisp-link-function 'yes-or-no-p
 org-export-interblocks '((lob org-babel-exp-lob-one-liners)
             (src org-babel-exp-inline-src-blocks))
 org-clock-out-hook '(org-clock-remove-empty-clock-drawer)
 org-enforce-todo-dependencies t
 org-occur-hook '(org-first-headline-recenter)
 org-from-is-user-regexp "\\<Conor Nash\\>"
 org-mobile-directory "/media/sf_Conor/Dropbox/MobileOrg/"
 org-export-preprocess-before-selecting-backend-code-hook
'(org-beamer-select-beamer-code)
 org-export-latex-final-hook '(org-beamer-amend-header org-beamer-fix-toc
                  org-beamer-auto-fragile-frames
                  org-beamer-place-default-actions-for-lists)
 org-metadown-hook '(org-babel-pop-to-session-maybe)
 org-export-blocks '((src org-babel-exp-src-block nil)
            (comment org-export-blocks-format-comment t)
            (ditaa org-export-blocks-format-ditaa nil)
            (dot org-export-blocks-format-dot nil))
 )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your problem is with the `org-agenda-custom-commands` variable.  In particular you have the value

```
("x" "Todo List and Agenda"
 (todo (quote (priority-down))
       (agenda "" (org-agenda-ndays 1)))
 ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (time-up))))
 ("/media/sf_Conor/todolistprioritydown.ps"))
```

which is the cause of the problem, at least I get the same error when I set `org-agenda-custom-commands` as you have and run `M-x org-agenda RET x`.  Changing it's value to

```
("x" "Todo List and Agenda"
 ((todo (quote (priority-down)))
  (agenda "" ((org-agenda-ndays 1))))
 ((org-agenda-sorting-strategy (quote (time-up))))
 ("/media/sf_Conor/todolistprioritydown.ps"))
```

"fixes" the error, but I don't know if it actually does what you want.  Note there are extra parentheses in 2 places: around `(todo (quote (priority-down)))` and `((org-agenda-ndays 1))`.

Comment: I never used that agenda, so I never saw the bug. I also had to remove the "Priority List" agenda. This was a really hard bug for me to track down, thank you! How did you test for this?

Comment: The backtrace said `(void-variable todo)` so I looked at your customization for `todo` and copied your definition of `org-agenda-custom-commands` and verified that I got the same error.  Then I commented out that section and found I didn't get the error.  Then I just had to understand what it was doing so I read the documentation for the variable etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the backtracenot a elisper also but I've setup mine using the following post,

http://nakkaya.com/2010/03/19/org-mode-in-your-pocket-setting-up-mobileorg/